# Redirecting specific list of urls from one asp.net site on IIS 7 to another

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect

I've been trying to find a simple solution for creating a list of redirects for specific urls.

I want to define a list of old urls that IIS can intercept and 301 redirect to the associated new url.

the old urls are local, the new urls are on a different domain.

the new urls do NOT have the same url format, they will be completely new and different, so I don't want a url rewriter that uses some kind of smart regex to automate this.

I was hoping for something where I can just pass in a list or xml file and it can take care of the rest.

Is such a feature built in to IIS or asp.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay I figured out how to use the Url Rewrite Module for IIS 7. it does indeed do this, but not exactly in the way I wanted.

however there is support for mapping urls directly in the module, so after a bit of fenagling I got it to work.

This page was pretty helpful in figuring out some basic mappings: http://blogs.iis.net/ruslany/archive/2009/04/08/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks.aspx

Answer (score 1):

after a little more searching I discovered UrlRewriter.net: http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/configuration

however it says the preferred OS is Windows Server 2003... is this just outdated info or can I safely use this in my IIS 7 site?

anyone have any experience with this module?

Comment: looks like this uses regex for mapping old urls to new ones as well... surely I can't be the only one who has a need for this solution after all these years...